# Creating a list in tcl with elements that in proper index positions

Tags: list, join, split, tcl, concatenation

How Do I convert the below string/list to a list whose first element is 1-81 second element is 81-162 3rd element us 162-243 using tcl

{} {} {1 -81} { } {81 -162} { } {162 -243} { } {243 -324} { } {324 -405} { } {405 -486} { } {486 -567} { } {567 -648} { } {648 -729} { } {729 -810} { } {810 -891} { } {891 -972} { } {972 -1053} { } {1053 -1134} { }

Thanks

Comment: Did this list come from splitting a string? If so there are better ways to extract words from a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to filter out empty list elements, the obvious thing to do is:

```
# Assuming the original list is in $list

set result {}
foreach x $list {
    if {[string trim $x] != ""} {
        lappend result $x
    }
}

# The result list should contain the cleaned up list.
```

Note that you don't need to do the `[string trim]` if you're sure all empty elements really are empty and don't contain whitespace (meaning `{}` instead of possibly `{ }`). But your example contain both empty elements and whitespace so you need to do the string trim.

Alternatively you can use a regular expression to test:

```
foreach x $list {
    # Test if $x contains non-whitespace characters:
    if {[regexp {\S} $x]} {
        lappend result $x
    }
}
```

You can however do the above in a single line using lsearch:

```
# Find all elements that contain non whitespace characters:

set result [lsearch -inline -all -regexp $list {\S}]
```

Comment: You could also glob-search for `*-*`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to accomplish two goals:

1. Remove all empty items from the original list
2. For each non-empty item, remove space

I would like to offer a different approach: using the struct::list, which has a filter command:

```
package require struct::list

set oldList {{} {} {1 -81} { } {81 -162} { } {162 -243} { } {243 -324} {}}
set newList [struct::list filterfor item $oldList {
    [set item [string map {{ } {}} $item]] != ""
}]
```

In this solution, I use the `struct::list filterfor` command, which resembles the foreach command. The body of the filterfor is a boolean expression. In the body, I use string map to remove all spaces from each item, and only return true if the result is not empty. This solution might not be the most efficient, but a different approach to solve the problem.